# Writing a C++ file to read lines of a text file containing white spaces

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream

I intended to write a C++ program that reads every line on a text file, and checks whether the data written on each line represents valid data. Only integers between 0 and 15 inclusive are considered valid data. The text file name is written as a command line argument (argv[1]) into the program.

The contents of the text file are:

```
1 2  
-3  
5  
0  
d  
15  
16  
3.1  
v7  
4  
8y  
2  
7
```

I wrote the following code, where `while (f.getline(buf, 10))` is used as the while loop condition because `while(f >> buf)` stops reading a line when encountering whitespaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/* A function that checks whether a line of data is valid.
The function returns 1 if a line of data is valid, and 0 if it is invalid. */

int ValidityCheck(char* str)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] < '0') || (str[i] > '9')) break;
    }

    if (str[i])
    {
        cout << "Invalid data" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (atoi(str) > 15)
    {
        cout << "Invalid data" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else return 1; 
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[10];
    
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        ifstream f(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (!f) 
        {
            cout << "Error: cannot open file." << endl; 
            return 0;
        }
        while (f.getline(buf, 10))
        {
            if (ValidityCheck(buf) == 1)
            {
                cout << buf << endl;
            }
        }
        f.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hoever, when I ran this piece of code, the program only printed out the last line correctly as 7 and printed out the error message on all other lines, like this:

```
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
7
```

How can I fix this problem and got the program to work as intended?

Comment: The last line in your sample input file is `8 9`. I would think that _should_ print `Invalid data` and don't understand how it could possibly be correct to print `7`. Also why are you opening the file in binary mode?

Comment: @NathanPierson I copied the wrong file. It should be 7. The mistake has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that each of the lines in your file contains trailing spaces. Therefore, you need to trim each of the lines first. I did it with a rtrim function. Here is the correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/* A function that checks whether a line of data is valid.
The function returns 1 if a line of data is valid, and 0 if it is invalid. */

void rtrim(char *s)
{
    char* back = s + strlen(s);
    while(isspace(*--back));
    *(back+1) = '\0';
}

int ValidityCheck(char* str)
{
    rtrim(str);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] < '0') || (str[i] > '9')) break;
    }

    if (str[i])
    {
        cout << "Invalid data" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (atoi(str) > 15)
    {
        cout << "Invalid data" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }
    else return 1; 
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[10];
    
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        ifstream f(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
        if (!f) 
        {
            cout << "Error: cannot open file." << endl; 
            return 0;
        }
        while (f.getline(buf, 10))
        {
            if (ValidityCheck(buf) == 1)
            {
                cout << buf << endl;
            }
        }
        f.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Invalid data
Invalid data
5
0
Invalid data
15
Invalid data
Invalid data
Invalid data
4
Invalid data
2
7
```

Comment: Hi @YuanLinTech if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> `while(f >> buf)` stops reading a line when encountering whitespaces

No, it doesn't. `operator>>` skips leading whitespace (by default, which can be turned off with `std::noskipws`), and line breaks are considered whitespace. `while(f >> buf)` will happily keep reading values, even past a line break, as long as the input stream has data that matches the data type of buf. If you try to read something that does not match, then the stream will enter an error state that you will need to `clear()` before you can read again.

Since you are coding for C++, not C, this task would be much easier to handle if you used `std::string` and `std::istringstream` instead of `char[]` and `atoi()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

/* A function that checks whether a line of data is valid.
The function returns true if a line of data is valid, and false if it is invalid. */

bool ValidityCheck(const string &str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    int number;

    while (iss >> number) {
        if (number < 0 || number > 15) {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    return iss.eof();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        ifstream f(argv[1]);
        if (!f) 
        {
            cout << "Error: cannot open file." << endl; 
            return 0;
        }

        string buf;
        while (getline(f, buf))
        {
            if (ValidityCheck(buf))
                cout << buf << endl;
            else
                cout << "Invalid data" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/wIgMu9)